# How many NPCs are in the Terraria Mobile Version?

Tags: terraria-mobile

How many NPCs are in the iOS version of Terraria?

I've checked the wiki, but it only tells me about the PC version. Does the mobile version have the same number of NPCs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game has a total of **21 NPCs** that can move into your house. They are:

- The [Guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide)
- The [Merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Merchant)
- The [Nurse](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nurse)
- The [Painter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Painter)
- The [Dye Trader](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye_Trader)
- The [Demolitionist](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demolitionist)
- The [Dryad](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad)
- The [Arms Dealer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Arms_Dealer)
- The [Party Girl](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC)
- The [Goblin Tinkerer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Tinkerer)
- The [Witch Doctor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Witch_Doctor)
- The [Clothier](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clothier)
- The [Mechanic](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanic)
- The [Angler](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler)
- The [Traveling Merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Traveling_Merchant)

Additionally, in hardmode you gain:

- The [Pirate](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pirate)
- The [Truffle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Truffle)
- The [Wizard](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wizard)
- The [Steampunker](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker)
- The [Cyborg](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cyborg)
- The [Tax Collector](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tax_Collector)

Finally, there is one event NPC that do not live in housing:

- [Santa Claus](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Santa_Claus) (shows up randomly between Dec 15-31st)

If you look at the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC) you can see a list of all the NPCs in the game. You can tell which NPC is only available in the PC version because these NPCs have a small icon of a computer directly after their description. It looks like this: [image: Computer Icon]

Answer (score -1):

The PC and console have about three extra: the witch doctor, wizard, and truffle. You can only get nine before the PC and console update.